# How to resolve "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument. error?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to do docker build with the following command and I get the following error:

```
C:\>docker build --no-cache -t myrabbit -f dockerfile_rabbitmq
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

My dockerfile: `dockerfile_rabbitmq` is defined and present in that directory. I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting this error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have not provided any arguments. You have only specified flags.

Comment: `docker build --no-cache -t myrabbit -f dockerfile_rabbitmq .` provide build context, it can be `dot .`

Comment: RESOLVED: I had to rename the dockerfile to `dockerfile` and change to the following cmd as follows: `docker build --no-cache -t myrabbit -f ./dockerfile.txt . `

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `.` at the end of the docker build command.

so your docker build command should be like this

```
docker build --no-cache -t myrabbit -f Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That was the issue; it's working!